# The Data in the template or the signers are not getting updated when Envelope is updated through API

Tags: api, email, templates, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I tried the below API to update the envelope. But other than the subject or body, none of the info is updated.

PUT -- /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}

I have even passed advanced_update as true still there is no change.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: template? or envelope?
Also, what is the JSON you are passing?
And the envelope is in what state?

Comment: @InbarGazit its envepe i want to modify. I am passing the same json which I used for creating the envelope, but with little modification of data. but it's not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because the envelope was already sent. You can only make updates to an envelope in "draft" or "created" status. Once sent - the envelope can only be updated using the "correct" flow.